# Enable Cors on Google Compute Engine

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I'm deploying a node.js API, and a website on Google Compute Engine, every thing works fine on my local machine, also they both work well separately, but whenever i call my API i receive the following:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'my-api-domain' from origin 'my-website-domain' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

i use express and i use cors middleware to handle CORS, and it works on my machine, but it seems google disable this kind of response headers.

my express setup

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const user = require('../routes/user')
const cors = require('cors')

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(cors())
    app.use(express.json())
    app.use( bodyParser.json())
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true
    }))
}
```

Note: 
I tried to send a get request to the api from the browser and it works and i recieve `access-control-allow-origin: *` in the response headers!

but when i call the same endpoint from the websites's origin these headers are not being sent.

Comment: What's your architecture ? Are you accessing directly to your VM? Do you use loadbalancer or other layer in front of your server?

Comment: What’s the exact error message the browser is logging in the devtools console? And what’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Answer (score 0):

- The error message is related to CORS and it shows that the [process was not complete when a browser makes a simple request to Cloud Storage.](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin#how_cors_works)
- Also I mentioned that to handle HTTP, [Cloud Functions uses a particular HTTP framework(Express 4.16.3) in Node.js (6, 8, & 10) runtime.](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#http_frameworks)

If you answer the questions by guillaume blaquiere & sideshowbarker, we are able to better support.